# Нужно возпроизвести WAV файл в Java приложении.

Tags: аудио, java

Нужно простенький код, который только запускает нужный звуковой файл. Просто в моем приложении иногда хочется чтобы был звук при некоторых событиях.

Answer (score 1):

Запустить этот код в отдельном потоке:

```
 Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip();
 AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("play.wav"));

 c.open(ais);
 c.loop(0);

 Thread.sleep(time); // Приостановить поток, пока играет музыка
```